# Implementing a synonym search with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf.js

I'm using pdfjs to loop through some pdfs and run searches for some search terms. At the moment if a match is found the line containing the search term is returned and stored in an array of objects. I now need add another functionality to the search, and implement some kind of synonym search, so that if a match is found not only it will return the line containing the match but also the lines containing synonyms of the match. I've done a bit of googling but I didn't come across anything that relevant. I've got no idea what this involves - well presumably some kind of array where I can store search terms and synonyms - so I was wondering if anybody could give me an idea or any suggestion? thanks

EDIT:
Right, after what you guys have said, if I run a smaller scale search, this is what I was thinking to do:
-Create an array of search terms and synonyms, like so

```
var arrayOfWords = [];
arrayOfWords[
    {
        "SearchTerm":"mySearchTerm1",
        "Syn":"synonym1",
        "Syn":"synonym2",
        "Syn":"synonym3"
    },
    {
        "SearchTerm":"mySearchTerm2",
        "Syn":"synonym1",
        "Syn":"synonym2",
        "Syn":"synonym3"
    }   
]
```

And then this is what I envisage could happen:

```
when a search term is chosen, 
    check if it's in the array (under SearchTerms)
        if so
            run a search with that search term
                get results in array of results
            get first synonym
                run a search with the synonym
                    get results in array of results
            get second synonym
                ...
        print array of objects
```

Comment: This is a problem typically only tackled by large search companies (think Google and Bing). It's not just synonyms, you should also consider typos, alternative spellings etc. For instance "mouse" might become "mice". I suppose you can go a long way if you have a dictionary of words and related words. I don't know where you can get such a dataset though.

Comment: You'll effectively need a full thesaurus stored somewhere, I doubt there are any you would be able to use for free, though you may be able to license that data from somewhere.

Comment: I think in an ideal situation yes, you're right, it should tackle a lot more than synonyms, but for the sake of simplicity we'll go with just synonyms, with all the disadvantages that this could bring.

Comment: Actually, synonyms are the _hard_ bit. Typos/alternative spellings are pretty easy to implement as a fuzzy search. They may throw false positives in some cases but, in general it's not a hard problem to solve. For synonyms, you need some sort of graph for words with their relations. This is NOT built into any language I know of, so you need the actual data and efficient way to traverse it.

Comment: OK, let's reduce the scale of the whole thing then. Say that rather than a full blown synonym search functionality then, I'll implement a small scale one, just as a proof of concept, so that I have 2-3 words and 2-3 synonyms for each? Would you create then an array containing the actual search term and the synonyms so that when a search term is used we know where the synonyms are stored...or something along those lines

Comment: @antobbo something along those lines. The actual data structure that holds this is not _that_ important, but you probably want to end up with a graph. Each word would be a node and it will be related to other words, which are synonyms. And each synonym then will have more synonyms that are not necessarily a synonym to the first. So, for example `rodent` is a synonym to `mouse` but a synonym to THAT is `periphery` when talking about computer hardware. When you input a word, you need to find it with its neighbours then.

Comment: Annoyingly, I did a quick search for `graph javascript` but all of the results were for _chart drawing_ libraries. Ironically, it's because "graph" has a synonym... There must be libraries/frameworks that help with graphs, as in, the data structures, so you don't need to do everything from scratch. There are also graph databases that let you store such structures. I suppose for a very quick proof of concept, you could do it as an object where a word is the key and it has an array of its synonyms: `{mouse: ["rodent", "periphery"], rodent: ["mouse", "rat"], periphery: ["mouse", "keyboard"]}`

Comment: I've updated the original question with some code and pseudocode, if I keep it simple maybe that could be one solution

Comment: In order to generate a list of synonyms for each word, I would probably use a database like [WordNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet).

Answer (score 0):

Without implementing graph data structure it can be done this way:

```
let synonyms = {
  word1: ['word1synonym1'],
  word2: ['word2synonym1', 'word2synonym2'],
};

const hasSynonyms = synonyms[word];
```

Synonyms can be accessed directly and it will contain array of synonyms or 'undefined'.

Main drawback - each new synonym record grows data exponentially:

```
let synonyms = {
  word1: ['word1synonym1'],
  word1synonym1: ['word1'],
  word2: ['word2synonym1', 'word2synonym2'],
  word2synonym1: ['word2', 'word2synonym2'],
  word2synonym2: ['word2', 'word2synonym1'],
};
```